# what to use Data picker in struts

Tags: ajax, struts2

I am using Struts 2 - The Ajax Tags in my project i added `struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar` to lib folder in my project,and `<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>` is also added,`<sx:head />` is added in header,`<sx:datetimepicker name="deliverydate" label="Delivery Date"
displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />`  is also added inside body tag in page but i am getting error as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory,
can any one help me,
 This my error log..

```
'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.LoggerFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.struts2.dojo.components.DateTimePicker.<clinit>(DateTimePicker.java:184)
at org.apache.struts2.dojo.views.jsp.ui.DateTimePickerTag.getBean(DateTimePickerTag.java:59)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:49)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_sx_005fdatetimepicker_005f0(login_jsp.java:277)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(login_jsp.java:196)
at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:117)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

'

Comment: it says that its unable to find LoggerFactory class which furthur indicates that you are missing core xwork jar.what all jars you have in your classpath? make sure you have x-work core in your classpath as the above class is a part of xwork-core.jar

Comment: i have xwork-2.0.7.jar this jar file in my library..My Project will run  before adding struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar file, it give above error only after adding struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar jat file..

Answer (score 0):

I think your project does not have `xwork-core-xxx.jar` file. Add the `xwork-core-xxx.jar` to your `lib` directory. `xxx` is the version no of the jar. This will solve your issue.

Comment: i have xwork-2.0.7.jar this jar file in my library..My Project will run  before adding struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar file, it give above error only after adding struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar jat file..

Comment: Now am getting Stackoverflow @ line 8285

Comment: thanks for replying,   its just giving POPUP with message stackoverflow at line 8285 , i am trying for  <sx:autocompleter label="Favourite Colour"
         list="{'red','green','blue'}" /> autocompleter textbox but not getting in jsp page

Comment: @RangappaTungal Did you read my comment? You can post your code, that will help in helping you.